# Eclipse indentation issues

Tags: eclipse, indentation

*(Note: this is a self answered question and I just wanted to share my experience)*

Working with Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 I set the general editor to indent code with 4 spaces. However, I wanted to indent html files with only 2 spaces and changed the HTML editor to use spaces and a length of 2 but nothing seemed to take effect because it was always indenting using 4 spaces. So, what was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I just restored default settings in the default editor (using 1 tab) and everything just worked as expected: The Java editor and PyDev are set to indent with 4 spaces and html editor is set to indent with 2 spaces. This seems to be a bug in Eclipse.

Cheers.